# iTextSharp C# windows store application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, itext

Before, I used `ITextSharp` to generate a PDF File in C# for Windows, and it worked perfectly, now that I need to compile it and run it in Windows store framework, i get errors: the major error comes from using `System.IO.FileStream` , which doesn't exist in windows store API, is there another type do the same as `System.IO.FileStream` in windows store app ?
Here the code I used before :

```
     String mat;
        System.IO.FileStream fs;
        Document doc;
        mat = textBox1.Text;

       fs = new FileStream(mat + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
           doc = new Document();
           PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
           doc.Open();
String texto = richTextBox1.Text;

           doc.Add(new Paragraph(texto));
doc.Close();

            this.Hide();
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work at all? Bear in mind that Windows Store apps use a different version of the .NET Framework than the standard Windows .NET Framework and iTextSharp is likely to be referencing the Windows .NET Framework assemblies.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx

Comment: Are you able to use `System.IO.MemoryStream`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes i am.

Comment: What is the code causing the error, what is the error? Could you edit your question including this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTextSharp is not directly compatible with windows store apps, the conversion work is not that much but it's not done. Have a look at [iTextSharp-Monotouch](https://github.com/mapo80/iTextSharp-Monotouch) for a possible workaround.